# How does the Faraday Cage Work?

Tags: electromagnetism

How does a Faraday Cage Work? Please explain the charges and why it doesn't shock somebody that is in it.

Comment: Where is your research effort? A simple search on Google reveals [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) which has fairly good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

No electric field can penetrate a region of space enclosed by a conducting surface. Because the induced charges on the surface cancel any electric field to zero. This also holds for a cage with relatively small holes. Therefore, anybody inside a Faraday cage (as in an airplane) is not shocked when the cage is hit by a lightening.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is that the cage is built such that the external current flowing along the outside conductors (usually mesh) cancels out the internal EM fields.